# HTTP session hijacking vulnerability on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, firefox, security

[Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) was released yesterday, a Firefox extension that makes it very easy to do HTTP session hijacking for users of insecure websites. It looks like Stack Overflow (and company) doesn't use SSL for the whole site (or allow an option to do so). Does that make it vulnerable to session hijacking? Should there be an option for full-site https like Gmail and others have?

Comment: My first reaction to this is "how secure do you need your SO connection to be?" You're not -- or you shouldn't be, anyways -- storing your credit card numbers or Social Security information here. I can see how it would be bad if someone started using your account to spam, but I'm not sure that problem is so serious that the team needs to implement HTTPS.

Comment: True, it's not near the risk that it would be on a banking site or even a social networking site. But it's still a vulnerability on SO and many other places... how hard is it to implement HTTPS?

Comment: While the personal info on SO isn't worrisome for financial or identity-theft purposes, leaving users open to session hijacking is just asking for account vandalism. If public wifi is my only option and I don't have a VPN available, I'll stay away from SO.

Comment: I'm certainly interested on the solution to this. I was reading http://superuser.com/questions/203816/what-can-an-end-user-do-to-prevent-sidejacking-of-their-browser-sessions and wondered whether the HTTPS version of that exists/works. The https://superuser.com/questions/203816/what-can-an-end-user-do-to-prevent-sidejacking-of-their-browser-sessions exist but its authentication username/password doesn't seem to work. Or did I do it wrong?

Comment: Bad news. Someone is *already trying* to hijack stackoverflow using firesheep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089665/firesheep-setting-for-stack-overflow

Comment: I'd like to see some solutions to this issue posted in the answers section, so we can vote on them. Increasingly I'm switching all my accounts (gmail, facebook, etc) over to use HTTPS because I'm always on public WiFi. Would love to secure SO too, if it needs to be. My one account is my gateway to 30-odd SE sites, and my reputation is reliant upon nobody pirating it. Not as important as financial info, but SE is popular and growing and increasingly our rep is very important.

Comment: @John Is your OpenID provider checked at every page load or do you login with your OpenID and cookies are created?

Comment: @TheLQ. Good tech point/question to (re)start the conversation. I look forward to seeing where the security conversation goes and to learn about the supporting technical details as answers (hopefully) ensue.